# Access localhost with domain alias via VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, localhost

I have a local development environment that I have setup using MAMP on OSX, on the default Apache and MySQL ports (80 and 3306).

In the hosts file I have setup custom domains for my sites, eg.

```
127.0.0.1    mysite.dev
```

I want to be able to access this site on my Windows VMs. Typically I would type in the IP address of my machine, but I need to ensure that the site is accessible from the domain alias (eg. mysite.dev) and not the IP address.

As per the instructions here, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326215/running-osx-mamp-test-server-on-virtualbox-windows-7, I have added the following line to my Windows hosts file…

```
10.0.2.2    mysite.dev
```

…to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your MAMP setup to accept external connections.  If not it is likely only listening on the local interfact (127.0.0.1).

Comment: How do I go about doing this? I have been able to access my localhost via the local IP address, so presumably this is configured correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I've made a very simple script that you can use to assign as many .local hostnames to you computer as you like.

You can find it here: https://github.com/Richie765/mdns-listener

There's also something called dnsmasq (http://dnsmasq.org/). I've never used it myself but it could also be a possibility.